# Poll with ajax in ManagedBean of @ApplicationScope

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have trouble understanding the operation of the `@ApplicationScope` when the request is made by Ajax.

I created a small example to facilitate understanding. Where I have:

- A `slider` changes a variable called `sliderValue` in a ManagedBean of `@ApplicationScope`, the value is set by Ajax.
- A `poll` which is updating the `panelGrid` to always get the updated value of `sliderValue`, the update is done by Ajax.

**Theoretically all users from accessing this page, should have the same value for `sliderValue`, and if a user changes the value of the slider, all others should receive the change, right?**

But this does not occur. Apparently, when the update is made via Ajax, he is behaving like a ManagedBean of `@SessionScope`.

When I change the value of the `sliderValue`, it is being changed in ManagedBean correctly, but other users do not receive the update via the update performed by`poll`.

I can only update the sliderValuevalue if I give a REFRESH in the browser and do a full REFRESH the page.

**Has anyone experienced similar problem?**

*index.xhtml*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Menu</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form prependId="false" id="form1" >

            <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid1"  columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <p:inputText id="txt1" value="#{menuManagedBean.sliderValue}" />
                <p:slider id="slider1" for="txt1" >
                    <p:ajax event="slideEnd" process="txt1" />
                </p:slider>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:poll id="poll1" widgetVar="varPool1" async="true" autoStart="true" interval="2" update="panelGrid1" />

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

*MenuManagedBean.java*

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named(value = "menuManagedBean")
public class MenuManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private int sliderValue;

    public MenuManagedBean() {
    }

    public int getSliderValue() {
        System.out.println(new Date() + " - get: " + sliderValue);
        return sliderValue;
    }

    public void setSliderValue(int sliderValue) {
        this.sliderValue = sliderValue;
        System.out.println(new Date() + " - set: " + sliderValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the value in one client (let's say, in Chrome), then refresh the same view in other client (lets say, in Firefox), and you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Yes, but I want change to occur without Refresh the page. The poll is being used for this, but he did not get the modified value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<p:poll>` submits/processes by default the entire form as in `<p:poll process="@form">`. Including the current slider value. You should have noticed it by an unnecessary `set` method call. Every open view submits its own current slider value during the poll. That's why every open view only gets to see its own slider value (leaving race conditions outside consideration when there are "many" open views).

Tell `<p:poll>` to only process itself, not the entire form.

```
<p:poll process="@this" ... />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: don't use `prependId="false"` ever. Get rid of it.

Comment: Got it, so every time he was back the old value!

Comment: What's wrong with prependId = false? It is an convention or there is a technical problem?